# PHP (Codeigniter) - display only part of text

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am creating myself a web blog system with Codeigniter.

For my blog posts, I only want to display first part of the post as a snippet.
I can do the following but this `substring` is for characters, not words.

```
$first = substr($content,0,20);
```

I want to trim first 20 words of the text. What function does accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `word_limiter()` in codeigniter.   [Reference Here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/text_helper.html)

Comment: That was so quick and exactly what I was looking for. Even Codeigniter!

Comment: I need to wait 10 mins for it..don't worry!